# How to sort mysql result but show specific result first

Tags: php, mysql

I have table like this one

```
id    name
1     John
2     Mike
3     Zed
4     Teacher
5     Aaron
...........
```

How to make mysql query to get rows in ASC order by name but put "Teacher" at the top or something that starts with "Teacher"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when name = 'Teacher' then 1 else 2 end,
         name
```

and for MySQL the following works since it returns `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`

```
select * from your_table
order by name <> 'Teacher',
         name
```

Comment: Wow... i've been looking all over the internet and finally found the solution. ORDER by CASE name <> worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(`name`,'Teacher') ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by case when name like "Teacher%" then 1 else 2 end,name
```

Names starting with Teacher will be on top sorted alphabetically, then the rest.
Example

```
Teacher
Teacher Aaron
Teacher Zed
Aaron
Zed
```